# Yamba - 301 Moved Permanently https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json

Tags: android, twitter

I follow the guide in the "Learning Android" book to build a Twitter-like application. 
Firstly, I used jtwitter.jar as a library. When sending a new status to a server, the app wrote "Failed", but the message appeared on the server page. Today I made some refactoring (bringing common functionality into an Application class and adding services) and after that I got `301 Moved Permanently https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json -> https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json`. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848001/alternative-for-getpublictimeline-for-jtwitter) advice, I tried using jtwitter-yamba.jar. The text of error has changed a bit (below), but it seems to be still the same.

```
E/StatusActivity﹕ winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: 301 Moved Permanently https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json
W/System.err﹕ winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: 301 Moved Permanently https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json
W/System.err﹕ at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:155)
W/System.err﹕ at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.post(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:219)
W/System.err﹕ at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.post(Twitter.java:1944)
W/System.err﹕ at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:2555)
W/System.err﹕ at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:2502)
W/System.err﹕ at org.my.yamba.StatusActivity$PostToTwitter.doInBackground(StatusActivity.java:93)
W/System.err﹕ at org.my.yamba.StatusActivity$PostToTwitter.doInBackground(StatusActivity.java:88)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The code causing error:

```
Twitter.Status status = ((YambaApplication) getApplication())
                        .getTwitter().updateStatus(statuses[0]);
```

where YambaApplication is a new Application class:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;

public class YambaApplication extends Application implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    private static final String TAG = YambaApplication.class.getSimpleName();
    public Twitter twitter;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        this.prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreated");
    }
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onTerminated");
    }
    public synchronized Twitter getTwitter() {
        if (this.twitter == null) {
            String username = this.prefs.getString("username", "");
            String password = this.prefs.getString("password", "");
            String apiRoot = prefs.getString("apiRoot",
                    "http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)
                    && !TextUtils.isEmpty(apiRoot)) {
                this.twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
                this.twitter.setAPIRootUrl(apiRoot);
            }
        }
        return this.twitter;
    }
    public synchronized void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        this.twitter = null;
    }
}
```

What can be the problem? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In the following post you will have the explanation about why that happens: [Authorization error with jTwitter for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006443/authorization-error-with-jtwitter-for-android)

I'm late to these posts - I was always busy to read, then I have to say that I changed twitter libraries version to the most recent until now (3.0.1). It seems when you do it, the error doesn't happen and the application works well.

You can download the last here: http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php

NOTE: I recommend you to download the ZIP and do the libs references to the jars on the jTwitter's libs folder - It should work in one shot.

There is a second version of the Yamba application. You can change your code using GitHub or trying the recommendations to stay with the previous code (Book 1st Edition): https://github.com/learning-android

Personally I don't know why Marko didn't do it easier for the Android newcomers and he should have added the dependicies later in the project. The good thing is that I have learned what they haven't there explained :)

Warm regards,

Leandro