# ProtocolException: Too many redirects (Marakana bootcamp twitter project)

Tags: android, redirect, twitter, protocols

So I'm working with this O'REILLY book http://tinyurl.com/q7uffb4 bulding up a micro blog android application connecting to twitter-like server : http://yamba.marakana.com/ using jtwitter library.

Connecting to server:

```
String username, password;

        username = prefs.getString("username", "");
        password = prefs.getString("password", "");

        twitter = new Twitter(username, password);

        twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
```

And everything is fine until I'm trying to get FriendsTimeline.

```
getTwitter().getFriendsTimeline();
```

I get

```
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594): winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects: 21
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:533)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.connect(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:153)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.getPage2(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:312)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.getPage(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:252)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.getStatuses(Twitter.java:1661)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.getUserTimeline(Twitter.java:1775)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at pl.histurion.yamba.UpdaterService$Updater.run(UpdaterService.java:79)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594): Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects: 21
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:300)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:468)
01-16 10:40:33.691: E/UpdaterService(1594):     ... 6 more
```

I think I made everything exactly by the book so there shouldn't be any mistakes on my part. So server then ? Should I start wireshark and try to find a lower level solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably its too late for you but others might get help. I found this post useful for similar query:
[Alternative for getPublicTimeline for jtwitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848001/alternative-for-getpublictimeline-for-jtwitter)